# Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /@|#|$|&|*/: Nothing to repeat

Tags: javascript, regex

I have to write regex which only has to select some special charactor. i have write below

samplem - https://regexr.com/4i59r

But when i try to initiate this like below it throws below error:

```js
var SPECIAL_CHAR = new RegExp('\@|\#|\$|\&|\*', 'g');
```

Am i doing anything wrong?

Comment: You need to double escape the backslashes because you supply a *string*, so your actual regex ends up being (essentially) `/@|#|$|&|*/g`

Comment: Or use a character class `[@#$&]`. If you want to match multiple use `[@#$&]+`

Comment: HI @Thefourthbird, thanks for the answer. post it i will accept

Comment: HI, i have like this https://regexr.com/4i5ps  but i want to remove " quotes

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
const regex = /\@|\#|\$|\&|\*/gm;
const str = `"name"@#
#
\$
&`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }

    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to double escape the `*`, the first backslash will escape inside the string, the second will escape inside the regular expression

```js
var SPECIAL_CHAR = new RegExp('\@|\#|\$|\&|\\*', 'g');
```

Don't forget the the backslash is used also to escape single characters inside javascript string literal:

```js
var x = '\*';


console.log(x); // *
```

Comment: You also need to escape the `$` unless the intention is to match the end of line